# Autocomplete delegate method xcode (not just listing and searching)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, autocomplete

Hi I was searching a more quick way to insert delegate methods in a delegate class via XCode.
For example if I implement the UITableViewDelegate I can write "-tableview" and Xcode show in the autocomplete field all the methods of uitableviewdelegate. But I have to scroll over ALL the methods.
Is another level of filtering possible in some way.
Something like writing "-tableview" and the continue with "didSel" and show only methods which begin with that string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before the suggestion starts, you need to type the full start like `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSel`, that means you already know the correct return value. But by that time you've already looked up the `UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference` to checkout the method.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the [Fuzzy Autocomplete Plugin](https://github.com/chendo/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin) for Xcode.

For example, this would allow you to filter to `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` by typing `- tabledidselect`.